# Как передать props из объекта или массива?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Видел такую конструкцию:

```
    <Component
      {...props}
      anotherprop={a.b}
    />
```

Какой должна быть структура, чтобы так переслать значения? Простой объект не подходит...

Указал в метках React.js, ибо возможно принцип похож.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все должно работать из коробки. То есть следующие конструкции кода будут валидны и не должны привести к ошибке. Первый вариант - передать массив в качестве пропсы:

```
<Component arrayProperty={['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']} />
```

Второй вариант, к примеру у нас в стейте будет хранится массив, мы можем просто передать его туда указав имя переменной, в которой лежит массив:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { arr: ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'] }
}

...

<Component arrayProperty={this.state.arr} />
```

Со стейтом показал просто как пример. Точно так же это может быть свойство объекта, в котором массив, либо статическое свойство компонента. Без разницы, все будет работать. Можете хоть `map` писать вместо переменой, все отработает.